# what's the meaning of "end on a note of" in this context?

Tags: meaning

what does "on a note of" mean in this sentence:

> Syria talks end on a note of uncertainty, U.S. frustration with Russia

Comment: read it as a *remark* or simply consider the talks end *with* uncertainty...

Answer (score 2):

It's just a trivial metaphoric usage deriving from [musicology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musicology). Classical music in particular often ends on a certain note/chord (which repeatedly either occurred, or was "suggested" but never actually played until the final "resolution" of the piece).

The metaphoric usage often occurs as *[a speech, etc.] ending on a high/low note*, which is usually a positive/negative reference to either the *content* or *style of delivery* (nothing to do with tonal frequency).

A closely-related usage is *"The US **set the tone** of the talks by starting with a robust denunciation of the Russian position"*.

Comment: +1 But I think popular music demands a full cadence much more strongly than modern classical music.

Answer (score 1):

NOAD has a dictionary entry for *high note*, saying:

> **high note** (*n.*)
>   a successful point in an event or period of time : *he wants to end his managerial career on a high note*.

In addition to high notes, there can be low notes, bad notes, ominous notes, and notes of uncertainty. Under its entry for note, NOAD says:

> **note** (*n.*) a particular quality or tone that reflects or expresses a mood or attitude : *there was a note of scorn in her voice* | *the decade ended on an optimistic note*.

So the headline you are quoting indicates that the mood at the end of the talks was one of uncertainty – everyone is unsure of whether or not any good will come out of the talks.

This phrasing can be used in a variety of contexts; it seems to be often used to describe the overall mood at the [beginning or end of some event](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=began%20on%20a%20high%20note,ended%20on%20a%20high%20note,ended%20on%20a%20good%20note,began%20on%20a%20good%20note&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).